# using sed to delete lines containing slashes /

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I know in some circumstances, other characters besides `/` can be used in a `sed` expression:

`sed -e 's.//..g' file` replaces `//` with the empty string in `file` since we're using `.` as the separator.

But what if you want to delete lines matching `//comment` in `file`?

`sed -e './/comment.d' file` returns

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `.'
```

Comment: From GNU sed's manpage: _`\cregexpc`: Match lines matching the regular expression `regexp`. The `c` may be any character._

Comment: Rather than using `sed`, maybe `grep -v // <filename>`?

Comment: `grep -v` is POSIX so that's good

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use still use alternate delimiter:

```
sed '\~//~d' file
```

Just escape the start of delimeter once.

Answer (score 0):

To delete lines with comments, select from these Perl one-liners below. They all use `m{}` form of regex delimiters instead of the more commonly used `//`. This way, you do not have to escape slashes like so: `\/`, which makes a double slash look less readable: `/\/\//`.

Create an example input file:

```
echo > in_file \
'no comment
// starts with comment
   // starts with whitespace, then has comment
foo // comment is anywhere in the line'
```

Remove the lines that start **start with comment:**

```
perl -ne 'print unless m{^//}' in_file > out_file
```

Output:

```
no comment
   // starts with whitespace, then has comment
foo // comment is anywhere in the line
```

Remove the lines that **start with optional whitespace, followed by comment**:

```
perl -ne 'print unless m{^\s*//}' in_file > out_file
```

Output:

```
no comment
foo // comment is anywhere in the line
```

Remove the lines that **have a comment anywhere**:

```
perl -ne 'print unless m{//}' in_file > out_file
```

Output:

```
no comment
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)